# DAO recordset Findnext with multiple criteria

Tags: vba, ms-access, dao, recordset

I am trying to use findnext on a DAO recordset with multiple criteria. It uses the first criteria but ignores the 2nd. ie, it only uses the first criteria.

Code as follows:

```
Dim rstWarrantList As DAO.Recordset
Set rstWarrantList = GetRecordset("Warrant List", "ORDER BY [CODE] ASC")
With rstWarrantList
sFindFilter = "[CODE] LIKE 'APO*' AND [Type] LIKE '*MINI Call*'"
.FindNext sFindFilter
end with
```

I can swap the criteria around and it wont throw an error, it only searches on the first criteria. I have tried using '=' instead of 'LIKE' with no effect. 
Ian

Answer (score 0):

Use `.FindFirst` with criteria for start searching, then use `.FindNext`, see help for reference

Comment: Hi Sergey, No luck with that suggestion. it still went to the first correct record that matched [Code] and ignored the criteria for [Type]

Comment: OMG, I found an error in the text string that I was searching. Cant believe that I didnt see it before.